# Jenkins build stalls on `'docker' is waiting`

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

```
Still waiting to schedule task
‘docker’ is offline
```

JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'docker'
            customWorkspace "workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
...
```

What is the cause of this error, and how can I diagnose it further?

I don't see any related containers running via `docker ps`.

Answer (score 0):

Relating to the `agent` named `docker`. They can be viewed on the "Build executor status" / "Nodes" / https://jenkins-url.local/computer/

Answer (score 0):

If you use node {} with a specific label, and don't have any nodes with that label set-up, the build will be stuck forever. You also need to make sure you have at least 2 executors set-up when using a single node (like 'master'), otherwise pipeline builds will usually be stuck, as they consist of a root build and several sub-builds for the steps.